# Java. JUnit. Запуск теста с набором параметров в базовом классе. @RunWith + @BeforeClass

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

Пишу автотесты с использованием Selenium WebDriver. Появилась необходимость запуска теста на различных браузерах. 
Структура:
Базовый класс, в котором и инициализируется драйвер.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
```

public class WebDriverSetting {

```
public static WebDriver driver;

@Parameterized.Parameter
public static String nameDriver;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    switch (nameDriver) {
        case "firefox" : {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Kornext_N\\FireFoxWebDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        }
        case "chrome" : {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Kornext_N\\ChromeWebDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        }
    }

}

@AfterClass
public static void closeTest() {
    driver.close();
}

@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection<Object> Browser() {
    Object[] object = new Object[] {"firefox", "chrome"};
    return Arrays.asList(object);
}
```

}

В дальнейшем в дочерних классах уже расписаны определенные тесты с помощью аннотации @Test. Изначально драйвер инициализировался в @BeforeClass и все было хорошо. Хорошо ровно до того момента, как мне понадобилось, что бы формировалось два теста с для различных браузеров.

В моем случае переменная nameBrowser выдает null что в @BeforeClass, что в конструкторе, что в @Before методе.

В целом я догадываюсь почему это происходит: @RunWith привязывается к методу @Test, как я понял.
Вопрос в том, как мне все же добиться результата. Желательно красиво и без переделывания структуры.

Comment: Почему вы вызываете экземпляр веб-драйвера раньше, чем объявили путь к нему?

Comment: Игрался с вариантами и не заметил. Да, вы правы, спасибо. 
Но увы, проблемы это не решает.

Comment: Не работал с JUnit, только с TestNG. Исходя из своего опыта, все тесты запускаются в одном браузере. Если нужно запустить тесты в разных браузерах, то передаю параметр, в каком именно браузере их буду запускать. Еще вариант, это запуск через Jenkins или другое CI, когда в одном случае запуска джобы передается один браузер, во втором - второй и т. д. Параметризация, как правило, используется для различных наборов данных в самих тестах, но не браузеров.